# How do I create a top navbar with a max size?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the "content" of my navbar to have a maximum size.
Let me explain, my navbar has a width of 100% but the content inside does not, I do not want it to have that size of 100%, I need the navbar to have the same size as the content of my page (in this case is an 800px example) as found in my main article.

I am creating my navbar with flexbox property

The containers:

```
<div class="item">
// Content A
</div>

<div class="item">
// Content B
</div>

<div class="item">
// Content C
</div>
```

represent an ul li a menu, another is a logo, and the other is a button

How can I do that effect?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }

        nav {
            width: 100%;
            max-height: 60px;
            background-color: black;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .item {
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #ccc;
        }

        main {
            max-width: 800px;
            background-color: #fff;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="item">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <article> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa ullam cumque nihil cupiditate sint
            ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam.
        </article>
        <br>
        <article> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa ullam cumque nihil cupiditate sint
            ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam. ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam. ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam. ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam.
        </article>
        <br>
        <article> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa ullam cumque nihil cupiditate sint
            ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam. ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam. ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam. ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam.
        </article>
        <br>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

### Updated

Ok, but the content of a div is not centered, it is left justified

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }

        nav {
            width: 100%;
            max-height: 60px;
            background-color: black;

        }

        .item {
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #ccc;
        }

        main {
            max-width: 800px;
            background-color: #fff;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .container{
            max-width: 800px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <article> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa ullam cumque nihil cupiditate sint
            ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam.
        </article>
        <br>
        <article> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa ullam cumque nihil cupiditate sint
            ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam. ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam. ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam. ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam.
        </article>
        <br>
        <article> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa ullam cumque nihil cupiditate sint
            ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam. ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam. ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam. ipsa nemo
            voluptatem minima amet dolore excepturi eos dolorem suscipit assumenda praesentium fugiat ducimus, magni
            quibusdam.
        </article>
        <br>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can wrap a <div> around your items and set the max-width there to be 800px then just add the flexbox to that div instead of the 'nav'

Comment: Ok, but the content of a div is not centered, it is left justified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a 100% width div with the actual divs inside to be 800px Simply keep the nav at 100% width, and wrap the three divs inside in another div with a width of 800px.

```
<nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<style>
    .container {
        width: 800px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Updated publication but the content of a div is not centered, it is left justified

Comment: @I'mnewbie set the margin for the new container div to margin: 0 auto; to center it inside the nav